# How to enable problem details (RFC 7807) in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http

I'm using `Spring Boot` **3**, and from what I understand, it should support the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), aka "*Problem Details*", out of the box. However, I cannot figure out how to enable `Spring Boot` (*web*) to return errors in this format. By default, it seems to return it in the standard Spring `JSON` format:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2012-04-25T10:56:28.294+0000",
    "path": "/api/v1/some-resource",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
}
```

How do I enable "*Problem Details*" (RFC 7807) in Spring Boot 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a `Spring Boot`'s [Common Application Property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html):

- [`spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled)

> **Description**: Whether RFC 7807 Problem Details support should be enabled.

> **Default Value:** (defaults to) false