# How to enable RFC 7807 error response format in spring boot 3 and WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have an issue enabling the RFC 7807 format to be used by my spring boot (v3.1.14) webflux application controllers. I am wondering what the proper way is to configure the RFC 7807 format for HTTP error responses from the two different options I have found.

1. Following spring framework documentation by implementing controller advice, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/ann-rest-exceptions.html#webflux-ann-rest-exceptions-render.

> To enable RFC 7807 responses for Spring WebFlux exceptions and for any ErrorResponseException, extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and declare it as an @ControllerAdvice in Spring configuration. The handler has an @ExceptionHandler method that handles any ErrorResponse exception, which includes all built-in web exceptions. You can add more exception handling methods, and use a protected method to map any exception to a ProblemDetail.
> 2. Using [spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled) spring boot 3 application property for WebFlux. This application property has the following description:
> Whether RFC 7807 Problem Details support should be enabled.

The only way I can get it to work is by following the spring framework documentation and implementing my own ExceptionHandler

So if I create a ControllerAdvice like the following:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {}
```

Then I get proper RFC 7807 format for all the different failure cases I test e.g. validation errors on payload, bad method etc.

When testing to set the [spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled) spring boot 3 application property does not seem to change anything in error response formatting though. Instead [auto configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3ed1f1a064a10e53adc2ad8c0b46a4b2c148ee21/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.java#L63-L72) ensures the `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` is used, which does not use RFC 7807 format.

I expected that enabling `spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled` actually would configure spring boot to use RFC 7807 format by default in all the error responses. What is `spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled` actually used for and what is the proper way to configure RFC 7807 format for error response on a Spring Boot WebFlux application?

I found a similar question already:
[How to enable problem details (RFC 7807) in Spring Boot 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888192/how-to-enable-problem-details-rfc-7807-in-spring-boot-3)

but from my testing enabling `spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled` does not work and that question is for spring mvc and `spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled`

Comment: From my tests it does work, it doesn't work for each exception which is then handled by the default one. You are actually using webflux and don't have regular Spring Web on the classpath?

Comment: I am using spring-web as a dependency. It is mainly used to have access to classes like HttpStatus, UriBuilderFactory etc. I am using WebFlux, whole application is reactive and using mono/flux.

Comment: @M.Deinum For what types of exceptions does it work for you? If you have an example I can do a test myself. One example for where it does not work in my case would be when one is sending a request to an API using the incorrect HTTP method.

Comment: The sample used was for validation. Make sure you don't have anything in your code that disables auto-configuration and rendering the `spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled`, things like `@EnableWebFlux` or importing the configuration etc. which will disable things like this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! this actually identified the issue we had. We had `@EnableWebFlux` configured which disabled the auto configuration, so the configuration was never read.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that our configuration class was annotated with `@EnableWebFlux` annotation which disabled the auto configuration. By removing `@EnableWebFlux`annotation and adding the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation to our configuration class we fixed the issue.

So with this change the spring application property `spring.webflux.problemdetails.enabled` was read by spring boot auto configuration and an instance of `ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler` was available for handling exceptions which means we got proper RFC 7807 formatting for error responses.